# Azure ApplicationInsight and Power Bi - live stream

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure Application Insights to capture and visualise all events that occurs on my webpage. I created a report in Power BI which requires from me manuall refreshes from time to time.

Question: Is there a possibility to establish a live connection between AppInsights database and PowerBi (online) in order to forget about setting up refreshes constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a pity that the default export to Power BI, and the Power Bi AI pack (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-application-insights/) need manually refreshing or a schedule.

A fully automated solution would be to use continuous export to blob (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry), feed that to a Azure Stream Analytics job (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-introduction) which in turn sends it to Power Bi as a live dashboard.

Some links for inspiration:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics
- https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Tutorial/Sensor-Data-Analytics-with-ASA-and-Power-BI-2?fromlegacydomain=1

If you don't want to use continuous export you can try this: You can manually push the data using the Power BI API (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-walkthrough-push-data/). In order to get the data you could use the application insights rest api, see https://dev.applicationinsights.io/. Whenever data is pushed the power bi dashboard will be updated live.

Comment: That's right! Thanks, I have managed to achieve continous data export from api and now all works fine.